# Should I use bracket or parenthesis in creating numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, these two syntaxes seems to be same:

```
In [3]: np.random.random((3,2))
Out[3]: 
array([[0.12612127, 0.81236009],
       [0.12289859, 0.89502736],
       [0.70360669, 0.51271339]])

In [4]: np.random.random([3,2])
Out[4]: 
array([[0.94723024, 0.55169203],
       [0.48919411, 0.22082705],
       [0.24072127, 0.88963255]])
```

So either one is ok?

Comment: It makes no difference. You can use any sequence type.

Comment: They are both iterables, so there is no difference.

Comment: There is a difference. Tuples are immutable so should be preferred. There will be no behavioural difference, but you should still get into the habit of using immutables.